# JQuery - Adding an html table column to end of table based on array data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I've been trying to figure out how to append an html table with a column of data.  A button will be clicked that will take existing data column in the table, save to an array, then do some math on it, then spit it back out as the last column in the table.

Here's the code I've been trying:

```
var c = $("#dvCSV tr:nth-child(2) td").length;//find number of columns in the table

var myArray = new Array();

$("#dvCSV tr td:nth-child(3)").each(function(i){
   myArray.push($(this).text());
});
myArray.splice(0,1);

$("#dvCSV tr:first").append("<td>Th</td>");
var n=0;

$('#dvCSV').find('tr').each(function(){
    myArray[n]= "<td>" + (myArray[n]*0.01) + "</td>";
    $(this).append(MyArray[n]);
    n=n+1;
});
```

Here's a fiddle I have been working on.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7mfrrt8s/)

I thought I could nest in the array values into the each function, but it's not working right.  I can't seem to find any other example out there to get it to work.

If it's possible to work with the values in the table without first converting to an array, even better.

The td values in a column (work will be done on all columns with values) need to have some math function worked on it.  So it's taking that td value * f(x) then placing that value on the same row as the original value in a new column to the right.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the purpose of myArray.splice(0,2); ? You remove some values in the array by doing that, and I guess that will make the number of elements in the array not match the number of rows in your table.

Comment: You can ignore that. In the final version there will be two rows above the actual data. That removes those from the array so that no calculations are done on them. In this case, I would just remove the first header.  But to your point, is it possible to handle that difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert Header's Columns into `<thead>` tag, and others rows into `<tbody>` tag, for best manipulation of **DOM**.

Elements can be create with `$("tag")` sentence; for insert new header, can use:

```
var tdHeadNode = $("<td/>");
    tdHeadNode.html("Th");
$("#dvCSV thead tr").append(tdHeadNode);
```

To insert the others data for the others rows, can use:

```
$("#dvCSV tbody tr td:nth-child(3)").each(function(){
     var tdNode = $("<td/>");
    tdNode.html(this.innerHTML * 0.01);
    $(this).parent().append(tdNode);
});
```

Method `html` return or set the value inner tag, method `parent` return parent node, in this case, is `tr` for the current `td`.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Thanks.That worked perfectly. What if I needed to add an additional row below the Th row?  In my final version, I have two rows of descriptions then the data. What I get right now in the first two trailing rows is NaN. I'd like to repeat the values in those fields associated with the column.

Comment: The header thing doesn't work.  But what I would like to do is preserve the text containing td elements and do math on the number td elements.